# Spring JDBC SqlRowSet retrieve with non-unique column label

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc

Spring's SqlRowSet has String getString(String columnLabel)

But if my query joins two tables that have the same column name, the result set will have non-unique column labels.

for example:

```
select a.name, b.name
from a
join b on a.id=b.id
```

And after running the query and populating a SqlRowSet object, I call.

for example:

```
sqlRowSet.getString("name")
```

Will it return me a.name, or b.name?

Trying to be specific, like using:

```
sqlRowSet.getString("a.name")
```

Will throw an error

Comment: I'd try it and see.  Use "AS ANAME" and "AS BNAME" to make them unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you have non-unique names, you either need to assign unique labels using the `AS` clause, or you need to retrieve the columns by index instead.

Using `AS` (note that `AS` itself is - in most database systems - optional):

```sql
select a.name AS aname, b.name bname
from a
join b on a.id=b.id
```

```java
sqlRowSet.getString("aname")
```

By index. To retrieve `a.name`:

```java
sqlRowSet.getString(1)
```